# Python: Check if a variable is NA in the if statement

Tags: python, pandas, function

I have a function that looks like this:

```
if (Var_A + Var_B <7):
    Do something ...
```

The issue is, the Var_B column in the dataframe has either integers, or NaN values.

If I write the function as it is now, it is returning error as `"TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous"`.

How should I re-write the function so that, if Var_B is NaN, just skip the comparison and return Var_A?

Is it something like:

```
if Var_B is not null:
 if (Var_A + Var_B <7):
    Do something ...
 else:
    Var_A
```

Or, I can do something more elegant without adding an if statement:

```
if (Var_A + Var_B < 7) and (Var_B is not null):
   Do something ...
```

Additionally, how exactly do I write the syntax that checks Var_B is not null? I tried to write `!= isnull()` and `!is.na()` but both are not working..

Very new to Python, much appreciation for your help!

Comment: Python equivalent of null/na is `None`

Answer (score 1):

simply do

```
df = df.fillna(0) 
# if you want to get rid of all NaN values and replace with 0

(or)

df['DataFrame Column'] = df['DataFrame Column'].fillna(0) 
# if you only want to replace NaN in a particular column to 0
```

Now you can proceed with adding/subtracting/ whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use if working with scalars:

```
Var_A = 1
Var_B = 2

if (Var_A + Var_B < 7) and pd.notna(Var_B):
    print ('pass')
    
pass
    
Var_A = 1
Var_B = np.nan

if (Var_A + Var_B < 7) and pd.notna(Var_B):
    print ('pass')
```

If working with columns ouput is boolean mask, code is changed:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Var_A':[1,2,3], 'Var_B':[np.nan, 2, 7]})

print (df)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool

mask = ((df.Var_A + df.Var_B) < 7) & df.Var_B.notna()
print (mask)
0    False
1     True
2    False
dtype: bool
```

But then `if mask:` cannot be used, because using array.

[More infotmation in link](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#using-if-truth-statements-with-pandas)

Comment: I tried both methods above, the first returned "TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous", and second returned "AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'notna'"

Comment: @DPatrick - what is `Var_B` if raise error ?

Answer (score 0):

Pandas has the isnull function that returns True or False if the column's item is Nan or no Nan. So try doing it this way

```
if not Var_B.isnull().values.any():
    if (Var_A + Var_B <7):
        Do something ...
else:
    Var_A
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try something like this, it usually works for me:

```
def func(a,b):
  
  try:
    check = np.isnan(b) 
    if check == True:
      print("B is nan")
      print(int(a))
    else:
      np.sum(a+b)
      if a+b<7:
          print("Something")
  except TypeError:
    print("Error")
  

for x in .....:
  for y in .....:
    func(x,y)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic function that does not require pandas to be referenced or installed, which can be handy for core libraries:

```py
# Detect Pandas NAType
# Unfortunately the pandas NA class returns itself with most python expressions so we must detect through brute force
def isNAValue(v):
    return not v is None \
       and v.__class__.__name__ == 'NAType' \
       and getattr(v, '__module__') == 'pandas._libs.missing'
```

Comment: If someone can find a way to optimize this without depending on pandas library, please let me know. I used to be able to detect with `v!=v` but that stopped working recently.